# Singular homology of product

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $X,Y$ be topological spaces. If I know both $\text{H}_n(X)$ and $\text{H}_n(Y)$ for all $n$, is it possible to calculate $\text{H}_n(X\times Y)$?

Comment: The answer is yes. Look up the Künneth formula.

Comment: I don't know why this has so many close votes. It's a perfectly fine question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was given in the comments. This is the [Künneth Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%BCnneth_theorem).